# ExtJS 7.3.0 GMap Classsic toolkit markers component

Tags: javascript, google-maps, extjs, google-maps-markers

During the refactoring from modern toolkit to classic, i found a problem with markers component - they are not included in classic kit.

From Modern Toolkit Sencha Docs:

> markers : Ext.data.Store / Object / Ext.data.Model[] / Ext.ux.google.map.Marker bindable

> Can be either a Store instance, a configuration object that will be turned into a store, an array of model or a single model (in which case a store will be created). The Store is used to populate the set of markers that will be rendered in the map. Marker options are read through the markerTemplate config.

Is it real to integrate this component into Classic Toolkit?
Can't found an optimal solution (if it's real) from the internet/documendation.

Comment: How do you add the google.maps in classic any ways? Seems there is no integration for classic yet.

Comment: @Dinkheller there is GMap Panel UX

Comment: The problem seems to be in GMap Panel UX, that inside `createMap` is call `Ext.each(this.markers, this.addMarker, this);` ==> panel.markers are added as a marker to  the map. In `addMarker` it expects a marker. Currently no support. BUT with that you can easily add markers as a store and on record-change you could easily update the markers. Just create a GMap.Store and add it to the panel. Should be a 1 day work.

Comment: @Dinkheller thank u Sir! I'll try this up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the classic toolkit, addMarker method expects an object.

FROM https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/classic/src/GMapPanel.js.html

```
addMarker: function(marker) {
        var o;
 
        marker = Ext.apply({
            map: this.gmap
        }, marker);
 
        if (!marker.position) {
            marker.position = new google.maps.LatLng(marker.lat, marker.lng);
        }
 
        o = new google.maps.Marker(marker);
 
        Ext.Object.each(marker.listeners, function(name, fn) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(o, name, fn);
        });
 
        return o;
    },
```

But you can simply implement the Marker, its a special record - but as it looks for me, they are not 1:1 compatible (position vs. lat lng).

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/modern/src/Marker.js.html

Here is a classic toolkit marker:

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.google.map.Marker', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: ['lat', 'lng', 'title']
});
```

---

All together

```
   // define marker
        Ext.define('Ext.ux.google.map.Marker', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: ['lat', 'lng', 'title']
        });
        
        // create map
        var mapwin = Ext.create('Ext.Window', {
            layout: 'fit',
            title: 'GMap Window',
            width: 800,
            height: 600,
            items: {
                xtype: 'gmappanel',
                gmapType: 'map',
                mapOptions: {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.712451, 150.311823),
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                }
            }
        }).show();
        
        // use marker as record
        let m = Ext.create('Ext.ux.google.map.Marker');
        m.set('lat', -33.732451);
        m.set('lng', 150.311823);
        m.set('title', 'foo bar');

        let data = m.getData();
        let {
            lat, lng, title
        } = data;

        mapwin.down('gmappanel').addMarker({
            lat, lng, title
        });
        
        // simple objects        
        mapwin.down('gmappanel').addMarker({
            lat: -33.712451,
            lng: 150.311823,
            title: 'Holmes Home'
        })

        mapwin.down('gmappanel').addMarker({
            lat: -33.722451,
            lng: 150.311823,
            title: 'Holmes Home'
        })
```

Fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3hnq